# Understanding ViewState in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback

I am new to asp.net and confused about ViewState concept. Is my following understanding right?

Suppose in .aspx document I have a form with text box and button.
Form has hidden input field in which data being posted is stored and on postback when page is rendered(for response) then data from previous hidden field is used to populate values in newly rendered page. If this is right then how data was first stored in the hidden field was there any JS involved?

Comment: The ViewState field is used to store roundtrip information that is not stored in <input> fields, such as extra details for datagrids (e.g. column widths).

Answer (score 1):

> The viewstate is loaded after page initialization but before page load.

- [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)
- [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Referred from : [ASP.Net viewstate questions on form postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514979/asp-net-viewstate-questions-on-form-postbacks?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I have already flagged this question as duplicate. However for you to understand the concept you can refer to the MSDN site. Below URL will give you the most clear use of viewstate and its working.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms972976.aspx